# Change Struts2 property tag default escapeJavaScript default to true

Tags: struts2, struts-tags

I want to change the default value of `escapeJavaScript` to `true`. This would help me prevent any script that has been passed by CROSS Site Scripting.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you inject so many scripts through <s:property/> ? :|

Comment: Unfortunately the application is going though security testing and stripping scripts are not helping in all cases.

Comment: Sanitize your inputs, instead of your outputs, unless you think your db can be hacked

Comment: Find/Replace `<s:property` with `<s:property escapeJavaScript="true"`.

Comment: I am actually sanitising the input, but there are some which are escaping the filter like ;alert('hello'); appended to a a parameter.

Comment: You shouldn't directly access url parameters in JSP.